# How do I edit multiple lines at the same time in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

How do I erase all the angle brackets on all 6 lines at the same time? I am using Pycharm and studying off of notes in Notepad++[>>>problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQo2o.png)

The input is:

```
[input image][2]
```

The expected output is:

```
zork = 0
print('Before', zork)
for thing in [9, 41, 12, 3, 74, 15]:
   zork = zork + thing
   print(zork, thing)
print('After', zork)
```

please forgive the noobness

Comment: can you provide the output what you expect. Your question is not very clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a shortcut for this called [square selection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/multicursor.html). I usually use place the cursor on the starting point from where I have to delete the text, alt+ left_shift and click and scroll to the end where u want to delete.

It should work perfectly in your case (Hopefully).

Answer (score 2):

Pycharm support [multiple cursors](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/multicursor.html). You can position your cursor at the start of the top line, double-tap-and-hold option, then press the down arrow until you're at the bottom line. Then tap fn-delete 3 times and all of the cursors will delete three characters.

This was tested on MacOS. Your platform may have slightly different key combinations. I have linked the docs for more info.